# Include the value of each not empty cell to a message

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I'd like to include the value of each not empty cell in the message to send, but I don't know which is the good syntax to use?

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
    Dim MailAd As String
    Dim Msg As String
    Dim Subj As String
    Dim URLto As String
    Dim Nom As String
    Nom = "User name"
    Dim Pole As String
    Pole = " POLE"
    Dim Texte As String
    Texte = " Thanks for the informations you send to me  "

    'Sélectionne la cellule correspondant à l'adresse mail de la ligne :
    If ComboBox1.ListIndex <> -1 Then Cells(ComboBox1.ListIndex + 2, 8).Select
    'Le mail est adressé sur la base de la cellule active :
    MailAd = TextBox7

    Range("A2:J32").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Dim StrBody As String
    StrBody = Sheets("FICHIER ADRESSES").Range("A2").Value
        
    'Copie = TextBox.2  'bien mentionner le n° de la texbox
    Subj = "Message à l'attention de " 'Objet du message automatique mais on peut faire réféence à une TextBox
    Msg = Msg & "Bonjour " & TextBox2.Text & ",%0D%0A %0D%0A" 'Corps du message
    'Msg = Msg & "Bonjour " & Selection.Insert & ",%0D%0A %0D%0A"
    Msg = Msg & Texte & StrBody & ",%0D%0A %0D%0A" & Nom & Pole & "%0D%0A %0D%0A"   'Corps du message
    URLto = "mailto:" & MailAd & "?subject=" & Subj & "&body=" & Msg & "&Cc=" '& copie
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=URLto
End Sub
```

Comment: You will need to loop over the range of cells and concatenate the non-empty values.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you are talking about the range A2:J32 and want the values to show in your "msg" string: (this is untested)

```
    Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
        Dim MailAd As String
        Dim Msg As String
        Dim Subj As String
        Dim URLto As String
        Dim Nom As String
        Nom = "User name"
        Dim Pole As String
        Pole = " POLE"
        Dim Texte As String
        Texte = " Thanks for the informations you send to me  "


        'Sélectionne la cellule correspondant à l'adresse mail de la ligne :
        If ComboBox1.ListIndex <> -1 Then Cells(ComboBox1.ListIndex + 2, 8).Select
        'Le mail est adressé sur la base de la cellule active :
        MailAd = TextBox7


        Range("A2:J32").Select

    Dim rngCell as Range, sNonEmpty as string

    For each rngCell in Range("A2:J32")
        if rngcell.value <> "" then snonempty = _
              iif(snonempty="",rngcell.value,snonempty & ", " & rngcell.value)
    Next

      Selection.Copy

        Dim StrBody As String
        StrBody = Sheets("FICHIER ADRESSES").Range("A2").Value

        'Copie = TextBox.2  'bien mentionner le n° de la texbox
        Subj = "Message à l'attention de " 'Objet du message automatique mais on peut faire réféence à une TextBox
        Msg = Msg & "Bonjour " & TextBox2.Text & ",%0D%0A %0D%0A" 'Corps du message
        'Msg = Msg & "Bonjour " & Selection.Insert & ",%0D%0A %0D%0A"
        Msg = Msg & Texte & StrBody & ",%0D%0A %0D%0A" & Nom & Pole & "%0D%0A %0D%0A" & VBNEWLINE & _
"YOUR VALUES: " & sNonEmpty    'Corps du message
        URLto = "mailto:" & MailAd & "?subject=" & Subj & "&body=" & Msg & "&Cc=" '& copie
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=URLto
        End Sub
```